# Find the value of $x$ which is correct

Tags: linear-algebra

I have one exercise which is $$(x+2013)(x+2014)(x+2015)(x+2016)+1=0$$
I tag $A=x+2013$ or other for many ways but still can not find the first $x$ value. please help.

Comment: Is this a question from an on-going contest?

Comment: It is from an examination for testing students in cambodia sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you let $y=x+2014$, then the equation becomes
$$(y-1)y(y+1)(y+2)+1=0 \Leftrightarrow (y^2+y-1)^2=0$$
So
$$y = \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2} \Rightarrow x = \ldots$$

---

\begin{align}
(y-1)y(y+1)(y+2)+1 & = y^4+2 y^3-y^2-2 y+1 \\
{} & = \left( y^4+y^3-y^2 \right) + y^3-2y+1 \\
{} & = y^2 \left( y^2+y-1 \right) + \left(y^3+y^2-y\right) -y^2-y+1 \\
{} & = y^2 \left( y^2+y-1 \right) + y\left(y^2+y-1\right) -\left( y^2+y-1\right) \\
{} & = \left( y^2+y-1 \right)^2
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
(y-1)y(y+1)(y+2)+1 & = y^4+2 y^3-y^2-2 y+1 \\
{} & = \left( y^4+2 y^3+y^2 \right) - 2y^2-2 y+1 \\
{} & = \left( y^2 + y \right)^2 - 2(y^2+y)+1 \\
{} & = \left( y^2+y-1 \right)^2
\end{align}

Comment: Sir how do you know it equal (y^2+y-1)^2? I know it is true but i just want to know how u do it

Comment: There might be a more elegant/faster way; but see edit (addition in answer).

Comment: I added a second way to do it.

Comment: I really love this solution but it might be abit complicated to find these factors for other similar exercise.

Comment: I have the feeling this sort of exercises usually require some kind of smart or handy trick; but there may be simpler ways to do it.

Comment: Yeah it is a simple one but it has to quick of making factor to solve it at the end

Answer (score 0):

$a(a+1)(a+2)(a+3)+1=0$ thus $(a^2+3a)(a^2+3a+2)+1=0$ thus let $a^2+3a=x$ thus $b^2+2b+1=0 so b=-1,-1$ thus $a^2+3a+1=0$ thus $a=\frac{-3\pm(\sqrt{5})}{2}$ and accordingly $x$ will be approximated

Comment: Sir but u forget to plus 1 at the end

Comment: Yes i edited saw question in a haste

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Set $y=\dfrac{x+2013+(x+2014)+(x+2015)+(x+2016)}4$

$$\iff x+2013=y-\dfrac32$$

$$0=(4y^2-9)(4y^2-1)+16=(4y^2-5)^2$$